# Advance Sentence Split

Tags: python, split, sentence

Python question!

I would like some help on splitting up sentences in a text file. I do not want to create a massive if loop, but I need to find a way how to split up the text file into sentences. I must do this without .readlines()

I would like to split up the sentences using periods, quotations, and exclamation points...BUT:

1. Periods followed by whitespace followed by a lowercase letter will not split the sentence
2. Periods followed by a digit with no intervening whitespace will not split the sentence
3. Things such as Mr., Mrs., Dr., and so on will NOT split the sentence of course
4. sequences of letters such as e.g, www.website.com, etc.)
5. and at last periods followed by punctuation such as commas and more periods (ellipses)

I would like to have these split up sentences from the text file printed out to the user. How would I go about this process? I understand basic string formatting and indices, but adding ellipses, surnames, etc. are going to make it a bit harder for me...

**Also going to be using tkinter to create an open file button and a drop down menu that allows the user to create a new text file from the output of the program one sentence per line in a .txt file.

Thank you!

**Here's what I got**

```
import re

punctuation = ['.', '?', '!']
exceptions = ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Ms.', 'Sr.', 'e.g', '...']
lines = []

with open('myData.txt') as myFile:
    lines = re.split(punctuation, myFile)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you've written so far for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Flagging as 'too broad' since there are a suite of questions and OP is essentially asking for code to be written for them.

Comment: Probably going to need to check out nltk otherwise this will be some ugly regex.

Comment: Well I can tell you right now you don't have to worry about creating a "massive `if` loop" since `if` is not a looping structure.

Comment: You should split on fullstop followed by space followed by uppercase letter with rule 3 as exceptions.

Comment: Yes, I know that if isn't a loop, but I'm saying that I want to avoid using a while loop with a bunch of if statements in it.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code

```
import re

punctuation = re.compile(r"([^\d+])(\.|!|\?|;|\n|。|！|？|；|…|　|!|؟|؛)+")
lines = []

with open('myData.txt','r',encoding="utf-8") as myFile:
    lines = punctuation.sub(r"\1\2<pad>", myFile.read())
    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines.split("<pad>") if line.strip()]
```

Comment: Hey I see you are a new contributor! Please make sure so always describe what you did to the code. The highest ranking questions on StackOverflow usually contain way more descriptive text than actual code. Keep it up ^^